# Combinatorial solution: What is the probability that exactly two friends are in the same class?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Consider three friends (one of which is called Jon) in a group of 90 students. The professor splits the group into three classes of equal size.

a) What is the probability that exactly two friends are in the same class?

b) What is the probability that Jon ends up together with exactly one of his friends in a class?

My Solution: a) Let's say we put one of the friends in a class at random. Then there is $\frac{29}{89}$ chance for the second friend to be in the same class as the first and a $\frac{60}{88}$ chance for the last friend to be in a different class. There are three ways of arranging the friends this way, thus the probability is $3\frac{29}{89}\frac{60}{88}$.

b) Because Jon is now fixed, there are only two ways to achieve the desired outcome, so the probability is $2\frac{29}{89}\frac{60}{88}$.

I have two questions:

1. Are these results correct?
2. Is there a way to get the solutions in a combinatorial way?

Comment: To get insight into the answers, it may be useful to approximate the problem and say that each placement is independent of all the others.  If that were true (which it isn't, though it is close) then for $b$ the answer would be $1-\left(\frac 23\right)^2=\frac 59$.  So...you know the answer must be approximately  that.

Comment: Similarly, for part $a$ the only bad outcome would be if each class contains exactly one friend so, still using the simplifying assumption, the answer should be about $1-\frac 23\times \frac 13=\frac 79$.

Comment: Hmm... are you telling me that my solution is incorrect? Concerning a) there is also the possibility for all three friends ending up in the same class, which I want to consider a bad outcome. I'll change the wording to make this clearer (hopefully)

Comment: Well, your edit changes the problem so that my computations are no longer applicable.  But the (approximate) method I describe is still good.  Work it out for the new versions of the problem.  The answers should be quite close to the true answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your solutions are correct.

For a combinatorial approach, we will treat the groups as unlabeled.

There are 
$$\binom{90}{30}\binom{60}{30}\binom{30}{30}$$
to select three labeled groups of $30$ people each from a group of $90$ people. Since the order in which the groups are selected does not matter, the number of ways of selecting three unlabeled groups of $30$ people each from a group of $90$ people is
$$\frac{1}{3!}\binom{90}{30}\binom{60}{30}\binom{30}{30}$$

To count the number of ways exactly two of the friends are placed in the same class, choose which two of the three friends are placed together, which $28$ of the other $87$ people are placed in their group, and which $29$ of the remaining $59$ people are placed in the same group as the other friend.  This gives
$$\binom{3}{2}\binom{87}{28}\binom{1}{1}\binom{59}{29}\binom{30}{30}$$
favorable cases.

Therefore, the probability that exactly two of the three friends are placed in the same class is 
$$\frac{\dbinom{3}{2}\dbinom{87}{28}\dbinom{1}{1}\dbinom{59}{29}\dbinom{30}{30}}{\dfrac{1}{3!}\dbinom{90}{30}\dbinom{60}{30}\dbinom{30}{30}}$$

To count the number of ways Jon is placed with exactly one of his friends, choose which friend is placed with Jon, which $28$ of the remaining $87$ people are placed in their group, and which $29$ of the remaining $59$ other people are placed in the group with their friend.  This gives
$$\binom{2}{1}\binom{87}{28}\binom{1}{1}\binom{59}{29}\binom{30}{30}$$
favorable cases.

Therefore, the probability that Jon is placed in the same class as exactly one of his friends is 
$$\frac{\dbinom{2}{1}\dbinom{87}{28}\dbinom{1}{1}\dbinom{59}{29}\dbinom{30}{30}}{\dfrac{1}{3!}\dbinom{90}{30}\dbinom{60}{30}\dbinom{30}{30}}$$